# R httr modify_url path is stripping v1 in the url with path parameter

Tags: r, api, httr

I am in the process of building a wrapper package for a web-based API.

```
library(httr)

path <- "datapoint/timeseries"
query <- list(onData = "Variable")

devsite_api <- function(path, query = NULL) {
  url <- httr::modify_url("https://api.devsite.com/v1/", path = path, query = query)
  return(url)
}

devsite_api(path = path, query = query)
```

The result of this is

```
"https://api.devsite.com/datapoint/timeseries?onData=Variable"
```

I'd like for the result to be

```
"https://api.devsite.com/v1/datapoint/timeseries?onData=Variable"
```

When I looked into the `modify_url` it function it seems to turn the url into a URL object which identifies hostnames, paths, etc.  How can I make this function work without introducing something like:

```
devsite_api <- function(path, query = NULL) {
  path_changed <- paste("v1", path, sep = "/")
  url <- httr::modify_url("https://api.devsite.com", path = path_changed, query = query)
  return(url)
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: But `"v1/datapoint/timeseries"` _is_ the path. At some point you need to include v1 in the path somehow, either in its initial definition or by pasting it. Your own solution looks fine to me, though I would probably write the code in such a way that the path is correct before passing it to the function.

Comment: Hey @AllanCameron, yes I understand that but what I'm looking for is a more elegant approach than what I proposed, because path could be prepended with a "/" or without a "/" and writing an if-else loop doesn't seem to be the right way of doing it.